# Fixed and Proportional bias

Tags: r, regression, bias

I have a question regarding the fixed and proportional bias.

The definition for Fixed bias is:
Fixed bias is present if the confidence interval for the intercept of the OLP regression line DOES NOT include 0. Fixed bias is a constant difference in measurement.

The definition for Proportional bias is:
Proportional bias is present if the confidence interval of the slope of the OLP regression line DOES NOT include 1. Proportional bias differs at different levels of measurement.

After my calculations I got this:

```
Comparisons intercept   intercept_lowerCI   intercept_upperCI   slope   slope_lowerCI   slope_upperCI
R  and N    -7.415353   -16.063226  -0.7961319  1.531090    1.0688148   2.135044
R and S     -1.924666   -9.005223   3.2447172   1.171921    0.8108998   1.666416
```

Which means that for R and N there is a fixed and proportional bias present. For R and S there is no fixed nor proportional bias.

Did I understand this right? Is it possible to have both fixed and proportional bias? Is it possible to not have any of them?

Comment: One does not exclude the other, so both are possible. You can think of it like the equation for a line: Y=Mx+b. You can have them that has uncertainty, so it’s got a mean, and a standard deviation. That neither include snort exclusive Weatherby has uncertainty which would mean it has or does not have a mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: As a suggestion for new questions, reproducibility is important.  You could show what language, what tool, and what data you are using by including source code, and some example or actual data.  In 2 years a well-built question can help the next person asking the question while something more ad-hoc doesn't get that kind of impact.

Comment: @EngrStudent thank you I will take this into account for the next time.